# Any alternatives to NSIS, Installshield, Advanced Installer?

Tags: gratis, windows-7, installer

I've developed some nice software, and now all I need is an installer for it.

The things I need in it are in the following:

- Must be free (not free trial)
- No or minimal branding
- Ability to add licensing
- Simple to use, not a huge learning curve

Comment: What did you use to develop the software?  If it was Visual Studio, you can  create your own (limited) installer.

Comment: @rrirower I didn't use Visual Studio, my "software" is just a little bundle of portable software for my friends, but I need an installer for it.

Comment: Why do you need an installer at all? Could you simply use a zip file to package it all? Specially for portables, an installer is just the opposite.

Comment: If you only want to create Installers for Windows you could also use the [WiX Toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/)

Comment: Yes, I've heard about the WiX Toolset. I've also tried it, its very good, however I'd prefer (not require) a cross-platform installer. Thank you though!

Comment: Notwithstanding learning curves, NSIS does the job well (on Windows.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you would like a gratis but full fledged and easy to use installer creator you will not go far wrong with [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php).

- Mature
- Support for every Windows release since 2006, including: Windows 10, Windows 10 on ARM, Windows 8.1, Windows 8, Windows Server 2012, Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2008, and Windows Vista.
- Custom installation
- Script based so can be included in a make process, (.iss files).
- Unicode Support
- Custom Installer Icons & Splash Screens
- Multistage Installs
- Multi-directory installs
- Multiple Language support
- Add to start menu
- Help/Manuals install
- Prompted Installs with Advanced Settings

There is also a IDE/GUI available to get you started.

[image: Setup Wizard] [image: IDE]

Comment: Yeah, I know what Inno Setup is. It's a really good product that I've used before. I'll try it again soon, but it's been constantly feeding me errors for no apparent reason.

Comment: @user4673279 - it would help to know what the errors were but that is more a question for stackoverflow or the mailing list.  When I have had a problem that wasn't clear from the error message I found RTFM and/or starting a new simple project, testing & then adding features till it broke normally isolated the problem quickly.

Comment: @SteveBarnes Yes I know that, I'll post it on Stackoverflow soon. But my issue is saying "Cannot compile file: File in use". Booting in safemode doesn't fix this either, so...

Comment: I would suggest using process explorer to make sure the referenced file isn't in use plus turn off any antiviral software.

Comment: If your app is written in Visual Studio there is an Inno Setup extension that allows you to write the setup directly in IDE without any editor.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going for maximum simplicity and ease of use, I might recommend just using [WinRar](http://www.rarlab.com/download.htm) to create what is known as a "Self-Extracting Archive" (SFX). This is basically a self-contained installer that will extract a bunch of files for you to a directory.

To do this, simply add the files you want to extract to a new archive and tick the "Create SFX archive" option.

You can then go in the "Advanced -> SFX Options..." menu, where you can very easily setup advanced features, like:

- Adding a custom icon and initial info text
- Adding a license agreement text
- Setup custom actions to be performed before and/or after installation
- Select the default path to which to extract the files, and set other options, like silent overwrite or fully silent installation if required

It's a very simple approach, and quite self-explanatory, you probably won't even need a tutorial to make it work. One hint that is not clear from the menu: you can use HTML in your info/license text if you want, and it will display correctly formatted.

Comment: This sounds very interesting. Didn't even know something easy like this exists. Do you know if this *SFX-Function* is also availably for free archive managers, such as [7-Zip](http://7-zip.org/)?

Comment: There is, but it's very limited, it will only present the user with an option to chose the extraction path, but no infotext, license, etc. - On the other end, note that even SFX archives created with a "trial" version of WinRar will have full and unlimited functionality (and as is well known WinRar never really "expires", besides a nag screen when you start it up)

Answer (score 1):

WinRAR is commercial: "You can try WinRAR before buy, its trial version is available".

A similar (self-extracting packer) free-to-use tool is already installed with every Windows, but quite unknown, because not featured:

IExpress.exe

(just type it in your command line)

Here are some links with more info:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IExpress

[How To Make An Installer With IExpress](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k976yEXX11k)

http://lifehacker.com/384658/use-a-built-in-windows-utility-to-create-self-extracting-archives